# Delete folders and contents that doesn't match a particular string

Tags: shell, find

I am using Radarr which renames my movies directory with the following format:

```
Argo (2012)
Arrival (2016)
A Scanner Darkly (2006)
```

So every directory ends with `' (????)'` but I'm not sure how to create a command to delete all folders and their contents that do not match this format. I would like to use the command in a script with cron to occasionally clean up my movies directory.

I've tried to find the files first before using `-delete`, but I'm not returning what I'm expecting.

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -type d -not -iregex '.*/[0-9]{4}'
```

I thought I might need to include the `(` and `)` characters but I'm having issues with adding those too.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression you're using doesn't fully capture the pattern you're looking for. Also, you'll need to escape the parentheses because they have special meaning in regular expressions. Do the following for your case:

```
find /path/to/movies -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -regextype posix-egrep -not -iregex '.*/[0-9]{4}$' -print -exec rm -rf {} +
```

This will delete all folders and their content that is not formated as "Movie Title (Year)".

Comment: This will delete all the folders without confirmation, be sure about it!

Comment: I ran the command in a test folder and it deleted all the files regardless if they were in the correct format. Any other ideas?

Comment: What about this one?

Comment: I'm getting this: find: warning: you have specified the global option -mindepth after the argument -type, but global options are not positional, i.e., -mindepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it.  Please specify global options before other arguments.

Comment: try this, and let me know?

Comment: 1st command output:
find: warning: you have specified the global option -mindepth after the argument -type, but global options are not positional, i.e., -mindepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it.  Please specify global options before other arguments.
find: warning: you have specified the global option -maxdepth after the argument -type, but global options are not positional, i.e., -maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it.  Please specify global options before other arguments.
The 2nd doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: It was just the order of the arguments. Both `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` are global options, meaning they affect all subsequent arguments unless overridden. However, they come after `-type`, resulting in the warning message.

Comment: OK I reversed the order of `-maxdepth` and `type` but it deletes all files in the folder regardless of syntax

Comment: For the last time, use this `find . -regextype posix-egrep -type d ! -regex '.*/\([^)]+\) \([0-9]{4}\)$' -delete
`

Comment: That command deletes all the folders regardless of syntax